# How to interpret a regression discontinuity analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series, python, least-squares

I am attempting to conduct a regression discontinuity analysis in Python and I'm struggling with understanding the results. I don't pretend to be a statistician and I'm hoping you helpful experts can lend me a hand. Perhaps I'm not even using the correct testing framework.

**Context**:
I have an app that I want to determine if it has a positive impact on improving a metric (or any statistically significant impact for that matter). Let's say the metric is a sleep score that can be 0 to 100%, but is usually between 50% and 100% (see the chart below and the following code snippet for dummy data). I have data from 90 days prior to using the app, and 90 days after using the app, and the threshold day occurs on day 90 (0-180 total).

**Note that this analysis is for n=1** (just my own data).

**Questions:**

1. What can I claim based on the results below? The pre-treatment coefficient is -5.83 and the p-value is 0.001. Is it accurate to say that "the treatment had a statistically significant positive impact on my sleep score", since pre-treatment sleep score is estimated to be 5.83 points lower than post-treatment? Or "Using the app helped improve my sleep score compared to when I was not using the app"? Or is there a better way to summarize the results?
2. What do I make of the R-squared score of 0.059? That implies that the model does *not* explain much of the variability in sleep score. Combined with the statistically significant p-value, does this suggest that there is a relationship, but the effect size is just very small?
3. If I want to extend this analysis to say, thousands of users, what is the best way to do that? Do I gather all of the data, compute a global average sleep score per day pre and post treatment, and then do one analysis like I've done here? Or do I somehow average the results of thousands of analyses?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much.

[image: image showing regression discontinuity with random data]

```
# create df with dummy data
dft = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-06-29'),
                    'metric': (np.random.randint(50, 100) if i < 90 else np.random.randint(65, 100) for i in range(180)),
                    'treatment': ('pre' if i < 90 else 'post' for i in range(180))})

# Define the regression model
model = smf.ols('metric ~ treatment', data=dft)

results = model.fit()

print(results.summary())
```

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 metric   R-squared:                       0.059
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.053
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     11.06
Date:                Tue, 24 Oct 2023   Prob (F-statistic):            0.00107
Time:                        16:56:17   Log-Likelihood:                -698.11
No. Observations:                 180   AIC:                             1400.
Df Residuals:                     178   BIC:                             1407.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
====================================================================================
                       coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept           80.1667      1.240     64.648      0.000      77.720      82.614
treatment[T.pre]    -5.8333      1.754     -3.326      0.001      -9.294      -2.373
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        8.285   Durbin-Watson:                   1.936
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.016   Jarque-Bera (JB):                3.861
Skew:                           0.010   Prob(JB):                        0.145
Kurtosis:                       2.283   Cond. No.                         2.62
==============================================================================
```

Comment: This is really just comparing the after and before means. It's not really an RD/RDiT.

Comment: @dimitriy Hi there, thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate - why is it not an RD? If I should just be comparing the means, is there a different way to do that, or is the regression still valid? Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: RD is about focusing on observations near the cutoff via weighting while modeling the trends flexibly in each period. You are not doing either of those. There is usually some story about how the probability of treatment changes at the cutoff for exogenous reasons while nothing else does, so the users on each side are comparable. You don't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretations of the coefficient are correct. The pre-app mean is ~75 while the post-app mean is ~82.5, so you can say that the improvement in the sleep score should be ~7.5 percentage points or about 10%. You can use your domain knowledge to determine if this is a little or a lot.

Unfortunately, the default OLS standard errors are wrong since they assume that each observation of you is independent of the others as if you had 180 users in your dataset. That means the SEs are too small, though I suspect that does not matter here since the data was generated without any dependence. With the simulated data, you can say that it would be unusual to see a difference like this (or something more extreme) if the app had no effect, so you can say that the effect is statistically distinguishable from zero. On "real you" data, I would use Newey-West or Prais-Winsten SEs instead, where I expect it to matter.

I would not be concerned with the low R2. You are interested in the app's effect, not in explaining all the variation in the sleep scores. You can always add some controls for the day of the week and holidays since that can improve things.

If you have 90 days of pre-app and 90 days of with-app data on thousands of users (so N >> T), I would start by plotting the data with each user's metric as a line. Add a lowess plot for the treated period data and one for the post-adoption data. Without clear trends (like your simulation), I would fit the same model as above but cluster the SEs within each user. This takes into account that seeing the same people on multiple days contains less info. There is a toy example with Python, R, and Stata code [here](https://theeffectbook.net/ch-EventStudies.html?panelset1=python-code2#how-the-pros-do-it-1). If you do see trends, I would include time dummies for each day in the model or maybe a less flexible time trend. If you need to do something fancier, take a look at [Miller (2023)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.37.2.203)

---

Miller, Douglas L. 2023. "An Introductory Guide to Event Study Models." *Journal of Economic Perspectives*, 37 (2): 203-30.
DOI: 10.1257/jep.37.2.203

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough explanation, this is so helpful and I'm learning a lot. I just have one more clarifying question for now. When you say "the effect is statistically distinguishable from zero", what metric are you basing that on? I am trying to figure out how to justify that statement with data, considering what you said about the default SE being incorrect. Thank you again for your time, you are a life saver!

Comment: I am looking at your p-value $0.001$ being close to zero or the CI of the coefficient $[9.294, 2.373]$ excluding zero. I know that if I use better time-series SEs, that p-value will increase a tiny bit, and the CI will widen, but it won't be drastic since I know how your data is simulated. That is what I base my SS claim on. But I can't say anything about your own non-simulated data or your users as a whole, except that your current SEs will be too small. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks so much. May I also ask, in a different vein, why the pre-treatment coefficient is -5.83, implying that sleep score is 5.83 percentage points lower without the app than with the app, but when we look at the pre- and post-treatment mean scores, the improvement is actually 7.5 percentage points? I don't understand why those two are different. (Maybe this is a fundamental statistical concept that I am having trouble with.) I suppose they are both within the confidence interval, so maybe it's not an issue? Thank you again.

Comment: I ballparked the 7.5 based on the means from your RNG in the Python code. It's possible I did the math wrong. Second, when you fit the model, there will be some sampling variability, so the coefficient magnitude won't match 7.5 exactly. It's the same reason you probably won't see 5 heads in 10 coin tosses. The negative sign comes from the fact that Python is using post as the base rather than pre. So the intercept is the post mean and the effect is relative to that. You can change that with `dft['treatment'] = pd.Categorical(dft['treatment'],categories=['pre','post'],ordered=True)`